# Apache Virtual Host ProxyPass two ports for internal (within local network) and external use

Tags: apache, virtualhost, proxypass

There are two URLs to the site. Externally it is https://example.com:543
and internally it is https://example.com.
External requests at port 543 are internally routed to port 443 and hence a single virtual host at port 443 but with multiple ProxyPass entries is being used.
The issue is at any given time only one of https://example.com:543 and https://example.com work by disabling one of the ProxyPass entries in the VirtualHost file. Can both co-exist and work ?

```
#  ProxyPass             / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:443/ams/VirtualHostRoot/
#  ProxyPassReverse      / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:443/ams/VirtualHostRoot/

 ProxyPass             / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:543/ams/VirtualHostRoot/
 ProxyPassReverse      / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:543/ams/VirtualHostRoot/
```

Below is the full virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*"          nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown          downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log           "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    # Balance load between 4 ZEO front-ends
    <Proxy balancer://lbyourorganization>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8081/
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8091/
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8092/


    # Use Pending Request Counting Algorithm (s. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.html).
    # This will reduce latencies that occur as a result of long running requests temporarily blocking a ZEO client.
    # You will need to install the separate mod_lbmethod_bybusyness module in Apache 2.4.
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    </Proxy>


    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    #  ProxyPass             / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:443/ams/VirtualHostRoot/
    #  ProxyPassReverse      / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:443/ams/VirtualHostRoot/

    ProxyPass             / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:543/ams/VirtualHostRoot/
    ProxyPassReverse      / balancer://lbyourorganization/http://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:543/ams/VirtualHostRoot/        
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, just to confirm: when you say "External requests at port 543 are internally routed to port 443", does this happen outside Apache HTTPD?  Is it possible to let Apache do this routing?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more your question, It is a bit confusing.

Comment: @RichardNeish - Yes, it happens outside Apache. The router uses Port Address Translation to redirect external traffic on port 543 to port 433 internally. This is because there are two virtual machines on the same host with a single public IP. Hence, port 443 will work only on one virtual machine externally. Hence, two ports 443 and 543 and the internal redirections.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to change the router configuration to point the external traffic to a different port than the internal traffic (say to 543 internally) and then to have two `<VirtualHost>` configs in Apache Httpd with the two different `ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse` settings.